# using actionscript3 components

Tags: flash, components, stage

Good Day Everyone, In ActionScript3. I have a couple of minor issues. I am writing a message in a text input component and when I click the submit button the message is transferred and displayed in the text area component.
My problem is every time I write a new message the older message what was displayed in the text area disappears which I don't and I want all messages to show.
Can you guys inspect my code and tell me how I can fix this. Its driving me insane lol. Thanks Guys Appreciate it

```
transfer_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
 function onMouseClick(Evt:Event) {
 if (input_txt.text) {
  output_txt.text = input_txt.text;
 input_txt.text = "";
    output_txt.verticalScrollPosition = output_txt.maxVerticalScrollPosition;

            input_txt.setFocus();

 }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try
`output_txt.text += input_txt.text + '\n';`

This will concatenate it, whereas

`output_txt.text = input_txt.text;`

just sets the output equal to the input, which discards the previous input.